# Why and how should I use prototype design pattern

Tags: c++, c++11, design-patterns

I am learning about design patterns and trying to implement them by myself. For most of design pattern I can understand there use and implementation but I am getting confused with Prototype pattern. Here is my approach to implement it.

**Ship.h**

```
class IShipPrototype
{
public:
    virtual IShipPrototype* clone() = 0;

    IShipPrototype(const std::string sName, float w = 10, float h = 10, float s = 10) : shipName{ sName }, width{ w }, height{ h }, speed{ s } {};
    IShipPrototype(const IShipPrototype &that)
    {
        shipName = that.shipName;
        width = that.width;
        height = that.height;
        speed = that.speed;
    }

    void Print()
    {
        std::cout << "-----------------------\n";
        std::cout << "\tShip Info\t\n" <<
            "Name:\t\t" << shipName << "\n" <<
            "Width:\t\t" << width << "\n" <<
            "Height:\t\t" << height << "\n" <<
            "Speed:\t\t" << speed << std::endl;

    }
    void SetShipName(const std::string &newShipName)    { shipName = newShipName; }
    void SetShipHeight(float NewHeight)         { height = NewHeight; }
    void SetShipWidth(float NewWidth)           { width = NewWidth; }
    void SetShipSpeed(float NewSpeed)           { speed = NewSpeed; }


private:
    std::string shipName;
    float width = 0, height = 0, speed = 0;
};


class Ship : public IShipPrototype
{

public:
    Ship(const std::string& sName, float w, float h, float s) : IShipPrototype(sName, w, h, s) {}
    Ship(const Ship &ship) : IShipPrototype(ship) {}


    IShipPrototype* clone() override
    {
        return new Ship(*this);
    }

};


class ShipFactory
{
public:
    ShipFactory()
    {
        ships[0] = new Ship("titanic", 12, 43, 47);
        ships[1] = new Ship("Black pearl", 15, 73, 24);
        ships[2] = new Ship("Man O War", 32, 46, 14);
        ships[3] = new Ship("Rose Marry", 24, 53, 52);
    }

    IShipPrototype* CreateCloneShip(int idx)
    {
        return ships[idx]->clone();
    }

private:
    std::map<int, IShipPrototype*> ships;

};
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main()
{
    ShipFactory *factory = new ShipFactory();
    IShipPrototype* titanicClone = factory->CreateCloneShip(0);
    IShipPrototype* blackPearlClone = factory->CreateCloneShip(1);
    IShipPrototype* manOwarClone = factory->CreateCloneShip(2);
    IShipPrototype* roseMarry = factory->CreateCloneShip(3);

    titanicClone->SetShipName("titanicClone");
    titanicClone->SetShipHeight(100);
    titanicClone->Print();

    blackPearlClone->SetShipName("blackPearlClone");
    blackPearlClone->SetShipSpeed(10);
    blackPearlClone->Print();

    manOwarClone->SetShipName("manOwarClone");
    manOwarClone->SetShipWidth(40);
    manOwarClone->Print();

    roseMarry->SetShipName("roseMarry");
    roseMarry->SetShipSpeed(130);
    roseMarry->Print();

    getchar();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Part which confuses me is that clone function returns the pointer for Interface, which means I can't store the clone in a different ship object, For eg. `Ship* ship = factory->CreateCloneShip(0);`. 

I thought the idea behind this design pattern is to create clone of a already existing object and then change some details of it. 
Is it my implementation which is incorrect or I am missing something?

Comment: Prototype and Factory are both patterns for object creation, so it's not obvious why you'd combine them in this way. Prototype is especially used where you have multiple _different_ concrete implementations of the interface (you only have one), and some code that doesn't know which implementation it's dealing with. I don't know why you'd want a clone of the Titanic (the first one sank), and the `clone` method isn't useful if the caller has to populate all the data itself.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887704/whats-the-point-of-the-prototype-design-pattern

Comment: @Useless Most implementation I see on internet uses factory with prototype as shown [here](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/prototype/cpp/example) and [here](https://gist.github.com/pazdera/1122349). Maybe I still don't understand the pattern and its use. From what I understood the general use is to clone objects fast without needing to create an object from scratch. So for my implementation, even tho my first titanic sank, I want to make second one with few changes so it survives this time. I thought I can do ```ship* newTitanic = Titanic.clone(); 
newTitanic->lookForIcebergNow();```

Comment: Cloning isn't faster than creating an object from scratch (unless your initialisation is slow but can be quickly copied). The point is to delegate copying an object to its dynamic type, so the calling code doesn't need to know what that dynamic type is. That's only useful if there can be more than one dynamic type in the first place. I think the dynamic type of base-class pointers is also the source of your confusion about the return value. That is, you need to understand polymorphism before this pattern makes sense.

Comment: @Useless thanks for an explanation. I know basics of polymorphism but still it seems hard for me to understand it. I will try to go over polymorphism again and then come back to this pattern to understand it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Prototype Pattern allows us to create a copy of an object *polymorphically* by calling virtual member function, which is usually called `clone(),` as in your code.

> Part which confuses me is that clone function returns the pointer for Interface, which means I can't store the clone in a different ship object

In general, an overriding function must be precisely the same type as the type of the virtual function it overrides. However, if the virtual function to override returns a (raw) pointer or a reference, there is some constraint relaxation regarding the type the overriding function is allowed to return.

If that's the case, the return type of the overriding function may be a pointer or reference to a derived class of the class type to which the overridden function returns a pointer. This is known as [covariant return type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type) of a method.

Now, with this in mind and focusing on the `IShipPrototype::clone()` virtual member function. It returns a `IShipPrototype*`:

```
class IShipPrototype {
public:
   virtual IShipPrototype* clone() = 0; // returns IShipPrototype*
// ...
};
```

Since `IShipPrototype` is a public base of `Ship`, an overriding `Ship::clone()` can return `Ship*` instead of `IShipPrototype*`:

```
class Ship: public IShipPrototype {
public:
   Ship* clone() override; // returns Ship*
// ...
};
```

This way, if you have a `Ship` object and you call `clone()` directly on it,  you obtain a `Ship*`, not an `IShipPrototype*` – though `Ship*` does implicitly convert to `IShipPrototype*` because `IShipPrototype` is a public base class of `Ship`. `IShipPrototype` and `Ship` here are said to be *covariant types*.

Note that if you call `clone()` through the `IShipPrototype` interface, the *static type* of the type the returned pointer points to is `IShipPrototype*`. The *dynamic type*, however, will be `Ship` if it was called on a `Ship` instance.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. if I change the return type of ship class, will it still come in Prototype pattern. Also is my ship example is right place to use this pattern or I am using it in wrong place.

Comment: @darpan1118 *Prototype* is for copying existing objects polymorphically – copying without making your code dependent on the concrete classes that implement the interface. Your factory contains a collection of `IShipPrototype*`. If you want to create copies from them through the interface, then I would say *Prototype* is the way to go. Note, however, that you don't have multiple concrete implementations of the interface `IShipPrototype`. You only have one: `Ship`. Therefore, you can directly store the `Ship` objects inside the *Factory* and copy them by returning them by value.

Comment: After reading your comment and some other sources, I finally understood what I was doing wrong.  Now I have multiple concrete class for ```IShipPrototype```. I was thinking it as a way of cloning the whole class which is wrong, we just cloning some basic configuration specified in interface. Here is my [updated implementation](https://github.com/darpan1118/PrototypePattern). Thanks for helping me.

Comment: @darpan1118 Also, note that for implementing the *Factory* you don't really need to apply *Prototype*, as you can instead store pointers to functions (i.e., `std::map<int, IShipPrototype*(*)()>`) that construct and return the corresponding concrete implementation.

Comment: @darpan1118 When employing the prototype pattern then the prototypes are becoming the factories. Putting the factory pattern in the mix obscures the example. A good example would be in Paint, when you want to duplicate an existing shape for instance.

Comment: @眠りネロク I removed the _Factory_, as this example is solely to understand prototype pattern.

Comment: @plalx nice idea. I will try to implement this. I think creating a stack of recently placed shapes and when user press some key combination clone the last element in stack to make a duplicate of it. Does this sound like a correct way to do so in real project?

Comment: @darpan1118 Could be through a stack, could be through selection on screen or could be a random element that's copied from a list. You really don't need to go further than, `obj1 = new SomeObj(...), obj2 = obj1.clone()` to implement the pattern.